# Firebird: fbexport unable export data

Tags: linux, firebird, freebsd

I have strange problem. Under Windows database was created. And now under FreeBSD I am attempting to export data into csv. Fbexport is works under Linuxulator (Linux binary). From isql-fb I can connect to DB and do any action like `SELECT`, but from fbexport - unable.

```
root@sms# fbexport -Sc -D /home/sms2/DB2.FDB -H 127.0.0.1 -U 'SYSDBA' -P 'masterkey' -F full.txt -A "WIN1251" -B ::: -Q "SELECT * FROM AGENTS;"
Connecting to: '127.0.0.1' as 'SYSDBA'...ERROR!
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -551
This user does not have privilege to perform this operation on this object.

Engine Code    : 335544352
Engine Message :
no permission for read-write access to database /home/sms2/DB2.FDB
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fbexport tool connects to the database using a server (in this case listening on localhost). You are trying to access a database in a home directory through a Firebird server instance on localhost. The Firebird server runs under a specific user (eg `firebird`) and this user does not have read/write access to the database `/home/sms2/DB2.FDB`.

The reason it works when connecting with `isql-fb` is that isql by default uses the embedded engine connecting directly to the database without going through the Firebird server instance running on localhost (if you'd connect to `localhost:/home/sms2/DB2.FDB` with isql you'd get the same or similar error message).

You either need to grant the `firebird` **group** read and write access to the database in your home folder, or move it to a location outside of the home directory (+ grant the `firebird` user or group read/write to the file).